# What is the best way to create sequences for a text prediction model?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

this is the text example:

The process involves similar requirements to other Creator tools, like proving you’re the account owner and providing legal information.
Once set up, you receive a payout for your reels at the end of 30 days, during which you can choose up to 150 Reels to count towards the bonus. Paid, sponsored, or partnership Reels are not eligible for the bonus.And, you can go back and make Reels you’ve already published eligible for the bonus if you’re within the 24-hour window post-publishing.

type 1 sequence Example

```
       features                                    

[['The process involves similar **requirements**'],          
['process involves similar requirements **to**'],  
['involves similar requirements to **other**'],       
['similar requirements to other **Creator**'],          
['requirements to other Creator **tools**'],
['to other Creator tools **,**'],
['other Creator tools, **like**'],
[' Creator tools, like **proving**']
]
```

type 2 sequence Example

```
features                                    

[['The **process**'],                      
['The process **involves**'],              
['The process involves **similar**'],      
['The process involves similar **requirements**'],  
['The process requirements to other **other**'],
['The process involves similar requirements to other **Creator**'],
['The process involves similar requirements to other Creator **tools**'],
['The process involves similar requirements to other Creator tools **,**']
]
```

The **bold words** will be the targets. I need some help on creating these sequences, the 2 methods above are my approach i want to know if they are better ways of doing this. I'm still new in this field

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to create sequences for NLP is masking. Mask (aka, redact) some of the words in a sentence and predict which words should replace those masked words.

Your examples are suboptimal. Both examples use fragments of sentences, the entire sentence should be used. Also both examples, only the last words are targets, any word(s) can be a target(s).

Comment: How do mask words or create masks. More explanation or a reference will be helpful